# vb.net - in a link button click event in code behind, close tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

In my click event in my code behind i am doing some inserts into databases, emails, but when i click the button i also want to close the tab after it does all this.

I have tried response.writing a script to close the window but that doesnt work. have tried the below but also doesnt work

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", True)
```

Have also tried the add attribute on button click to close the window but i dont want to add the attribute on the button click i want to execute the attribute on button click.

If i also try the add attribute on the page load, it will close the window but will not carry out the code behind function

Comment: A more user-friendly thing to do would simply be to display some sort of "operation succeeded" message to the user, so they know everything worked as intended, and then let them choose whether to close the window - it's their browser, after all. Also if the window just disappears they might think there's a problem - it's quite unusual to just make an application disappear without any feedback, that tends to suggest to people that it's crashed. This is just my opinion, clearly it doesn't answer your actual question but I'm suggesting you reconsider the overall approach instead.

Comment: @ADyson - that makes more sense thank you very much! what i am doing is opening a new tab to upload a comment, is there a way that when the user closese the tab the parent window will refresh? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly, have a look: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=refresh+parent+window+when+child+window+is+closed+using+javascript&oq=refresh+parent+window+whn&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.5607j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @ADyson - What if the code is in response to a button they clicked? If the button says something like "Return to..." - the "to" being the tab they were on before they opened this particular new tab.  The "return to" button click **is** the end user choosing to close the window.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet yeah that's fine, that's the user's choice. Different from closing is automatically without warning, which was the original thing this question asked about.

Comment: @ADyson - I can't get the window.close() function to fire properly in code behind. I just resorted to not opening a new tab for my function, and then re-navigating the existing tab back to where they have opted to go. You'd think something as seemingly basic as closing a window would not take contortions of this magnitude.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet it's hard for anyone to help you with that just based on your comment. If you have a specific problem with your version of the code, ask a new question about it please with all the relevant code and details available. (You can always include a link to this one as a reference if you think it's relevant.)

Comment: @ADyson - I'd think an answer that dealt with the functionality the person posting this question wanted, instead of advising the person not to do that, would possibly tell me what I need to get it to work.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I'm not going to do that because 1) two years after it was first asked, I still think it's a terrible, anti-user requirement in the first place, so I won't write an answer to help condone making an unfriendly UI which fails to tell the user if their operation succeeded or not, and 2) I've (thankfully) forgotten more than I ever knew about WebForms and can't remember how all the RegisterScriptBlock horror show works (it was always awful to get working)...

Comment: @PoleHoleSet (cont'd) ...and 3) the scenario OP describes would probably have been better implemented using AJAX in the first place. I don't know why your app has a similar popup/additional tab, you didn't say, but it's possible you might also be able to achieve your goal with a better overall approach too. You say you want to do this after a "Return to" button click - but then why not just do that with Javascript directly in the page instead, instead of messing about with postbacks and injecting scripts? If you just want to close the tab when a button's clicked, there's no need to post back.

Comment: @ADyson - I'm not asking you to. I commented on something that I see as a common type of feedback on here - instead of giving someone an answer, we tell them not to presume to tell the user what to do. However, like in my case, sometimes we have a slightly different scenario, where an answer to this question might have helped me, instead of needing to post a new question with all kinds of documentation and details. If one has concerns about a philosophy, include that, but answers are used by others for their situations, so answering, when asked, would have been helpful for subsequent users.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet maybe. But any answer should primarily address the original requirement of the question. And the best solution to that specific situation was "Don't do it like that in the first place. Arguably it's an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It's like the old joke - a man is lost while out driving. He stops to ask a farmer in a nearby field for directions. He asks the farmer "How do I get to the city?" And the farmer replies, "Well if I were you, I wouldn't start from here.".

Comment: @PoloHoleSet ..cont'd: I suppose if OP had asked a clean question about just closing a tab, it might have been answered, but arguably it's fortunate that the suggestion was made not to approach the overall problem in this way. There's always a context to every problem - hence why you see this kind of feedback frequently, and hence why we encourage questions about specific problems and situations, not just tutorial-style "how do I X" posts. That's how I see it anyway, and I think many others do too. We should encourage good design as well as just demonstrating simple individual functions.

Comment: But there's no reason why you can't make that suggestion while still answering the technical aspects of the question, because we are told we're supposed to look for questions and to avoid duplicating ones that are already out there before asking for ourselves.